# Mapster context is null in nested mappings

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapster

How I can use MapContext.Current in nested mappings? For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Src {
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }  
}

public class Dst {
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

TypeAdapterConfig<Foo, Bar>
    .NewConfig()
    .Map(d => d.Name, s => (string)MapContext.Current.Parameters["prefix"] + s.Name);

TypeAdapterConfig<Src, Dst>
    .NewConfig()
    .Map(d => d.Bars, s => s.Foos)
    .Map(d => d.Name, s => (string)MapContext.Current.Parameters["prefix"]);
    
var src = new Src 
{
    Foos = new [] { "test" }
};  

var dst = src
    .BuildAdapter()
    .AddParameter("prefix", "!")
    .AdaptToType<Dst>();
```

When i try to map a src into dst i get `Null reference exception` for `MapContext.Current` on attempt to map Foos into Bars. Context works for top level mappings (Dst.Name will be set) but is not accessible on nested mappings. How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you solve it? I ran into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It works for me if I explicitly add the call to create the `MapScopeContext`:

```
using var contextScope = new MapContextScope();
```

Anyway, the `ServiceMapper` implementation should already add it as found in source code.
Additionally, it used to work for me, but in a new XUnit test project I'm getting the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping must be called using ServiceAdapter
            at Mapster.TypeAdapterExtensions.GetService[TService](MapContext context)
```

and debugging I found that the `MapContext.Current` property is `null`.

I would like to understand why I'm getting this inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When using `item.Adapt<OtherClass>(mapper.Config)` I get the exception as mentioned above, however when using `mapper.Map<OtherClass>(item)` it works fine with `MapContext.Current.GetService<SomeService>()` in the mapping configuration.

Given that you use DI and an instance of `TypeAdapterConfig` is registered as Singleton and `ServiceMapper` (not `Mapper` because `ServiceMapper` creates a new Context when calling `Map<T>` which Mapper does not do) is registered via `IMapper` as scoped service.
Internally Mapster ensures that `MapContext` is not null when using `Map<T>` instead of `Adapt<T>`

So like this for DI:

```
var typeAdapterConfig = new TypeAdapterConfig();
typeAdapterConfig.Scan(...);
typeAdapterConfig.Compile();

services
    .AddSingleton(typeAdapterConfig)
    .AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
```

Mapping:

```
public class IdMappingConfiguration : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        _ = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

        _ = config
            .NewConfig<PocoId, DtoId>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => MapContext.Current.GetService<SomeService>().Do(src.Id));
    }
}
```

And resolving:

```
_mapper.Map<DtoId>(idPoco);
```

Internally Mapster works like this `MapsterMapper.ServiceMapper` making sure the context is present:

```
public override TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
{
    using var scope = new MapContextScope();
    scope.Context.Parameters[DI_KEY] = _serviceProvider;
    return base.Map<TDestination>(source);
}
```

In case you want to update a POCO by using a DTO:

```
var poco = await this._dataContext.SomeEntities.FirstAsync();
            
_mapper.From(dto).AdaptTo(poco);

await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Adding this open issue on GitHub for reference https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/issues/230